# StructureMap lifetime scopes

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, unity-container, structuremap

In Unity, there is (at least there used to be; haven't check newer versions) a "singleton-per-resolve" lifetime scope. Does StructureMap have an equivalent?

To explain a bit further, say we have:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent(ChildA childA, ChildB childB) { }
}

public class ChildA
{
    public ChildA(IFoo foo)
}

public class ChildB
{
    public ChildB(IFoo foo)
}
```

And I did a:

```
container.GetInstance<Parent>();
```

Is there a way to configure StructureMap so that the IFoo's getting injected are the same instance, but only for each GetInstance()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to look it up in [my book](http://affiliate.manning.com/idevaffiliate.php?id=1150_236), but this is called *PerRequest*, and is actually the default lifestyle.

Here's a test using StructureMap 2.6.4.1 that demonstrates this:

```
[<Fact>]
let DefaultLifetimeIsPerRequest() =
    use container = new Container(fun r -> r.For<IFoo>().Use<Foo>() |> ignore)
    let actual = container.GetInstance<Parent>()
    test <@ actual.ChildA.Foo = actual.ChildB.Foo @>
```